# does my affiliation affect the decision of accepting my paper in a journal

Tags: publications

Many times, you receive comments such as:I am unable to accept your manuscript for publication in "Journal name" The reason for this decision is that in its current state, the level of English throughout your manuscript does not meet the journal's required standard.
The work was revised thoughtfully and reach reviewing stage in higher impact journal but was not accepted because of scientific disagreement.

Comment: Your question is unclear I'm afraid. The title asks one question, while the text seems to be talking about something else, with the first part referring to "level of English" and the second referring to "scientific disagreement".

Comment: I think the question is: Will the journal reject my paper because they think authors with an affiliation at a non-English speaking university cannot write in English?  And the answer is that they should not, but they might.  Only the editors and reviewers will know for sure.

Comment: Your last line does show the level of English...

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking if it is possible that due to your affiliation, your paper is rejected for bogus reasons.

While this cannot be ruled out with certainty, such cases should be very rare in reputable journals. Reviewers are advised to only take the scientific content and the clarity of the presentation into account.

It is quite common that a presentation that is quite hard to follow makes the reviewer unable to assess the scientific contribution. This is because the reviewer shouldn't guess what is meant to make her/his judgment. If a central part is unclear, then this precludes the reviewer from supporting acceptance. If a follow-up submission is made with an improved presentation,  only then, the reviewers can check the scientific content properly and recommend to accept or reject the paper. Getting the improved version rejected (again) is not a sign of discrimination, but rather one should see the first try as a paper draft that has not actually been reviewed due to lack of clarity.

Note that many scientific communities are close-knit, so if an author needlessly does not adhere to the standards of the community in terms of the type of experimental evaluation, the arguments used, or the questions being answered, then this can also lead to little interest by the journal to accept a paper.

Answer (score 2):

> Many times, you receive comments such as:I am unable to accept your manuscript for publication in "Journal name" The reason for this decision is that in its current state, the level of English throughout your manuscript does not meet the journal's required standard. The work was revised thoughtfully and reach reviewing stage in higher impact journal but was not accepted because of scientific disagreement.

Your "question" actually answers itself, though it may not be apparent to you. I don't want to be mean, but it's written in bad English;

- It doesn't contain a clear question.
- It makes it hard to distinguish between your own text and text that you are quoting.
- It has some grammatical errors.

I assume that the question you want to ask is: **"why does Journal B reject my paper because they think the level of English is below their standard, when a more prestigious Journal A previously rejected it because of scientific disagreement?"**

I can't say for sure, because I haven't seen your paper and I don't know which journals you sent it to. But I suspect the following:

- The editor of **Journal A** looked at your manuscript, thought it was scientifically interesting and that reviewers would be able to help fix any language issues. But the reviewers disagreed with your scientific ideas.
- The editor **Journal B** looked at your manuscript, didn't like the level of language, and rejected it for that reason.

I would advise you to seek out some colleague scientists for whom English is a first language, and get their opinion on your writing style. Many mistakes are harder to see for people who did not learn English as their native language.

It may seem unfair that your manuscript would be rejected for language reasons instead of scientific reasons. But if the language in a paper is bad, it makes the ideas in the paper look bad too. If you want to be taken seriously, then language is important.

You should never rely only on your own revision, no matter how much work you put into it. You should always get other people to look at it too, because they can see mistakes you wouldn't notice.